# C# not connecting to R using RDotNet

Tags: c#, r, interface, com, r.net

I am trying to interface C# to R using `RDotNet`.

The following code is wants R to calculate the sum of two numbers and C# to get the result back and display it in the command window.

```
using System;
using RDotNet;

namespace rcon
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dllPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\i386";

        REngine.SetDllDirectory(dllPath);
        REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");

        //REngine engine = REngine.GetInstanceFromID("RDotNet");

        using (REngine engine = REngine.GetInstanceFromID("RDotNet"))
        {
            var x = engine.Evaluate("x <- 1 + 2");
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
}
```

but when I try to send the command to R and get back the calue in x I got an error:

> "InvalidOperationException was unhandled"
>
> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

If I explore the object "engine" I see that `IsRunning=false`.

Can this be the problem? And how can I fix this in order to be able to interface to R?

Comment: `are you missing a "\"` at the end of this `string dllPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\i386"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have outdated version of R.NET.

From [R.NET project documentation](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation)

> R.NET 1.5.10 and subsequent versions include significant changes
>   notably to alleviate two stumbling blocks often dealt with by users:
>   paths to the R shared library, and preventing multiple engine
>   initializations.

You can update your R.NET using NuGet manager from Visual Studio. See the same documentation page for detals.

Here is code sample from the same documentatin page - note that initialization of `REngine` is significantly simpler now (as now Rengine looks at the Registry settings set up by the R installer):

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(); // <-- May be omitted; the next line would call it.
REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
// A somewhat contrived but customary Hello World:
CharacterVector charVec = engine.CreateCharacterVector(new[] { "Hello, R world!, .NET speaking" });
engine.SetSymbol("greetings", charVec);
engine.Evaluate("str(greetings)"); // print out in the console
string[] a = engine.Evaluate("'Hi there .NET, from the R engine'").AsCharacter().ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("R answered: '{0}'", a[0]);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program");
Console.ReadKey();
engine.Dispose();
```