# Multi-windows R graphs in C# with RDotNet

Tags: c#, r, charts, windows-forms-designer, r.net

I have a C# code for a simple windows form with 3 buttons. 
Button 1 calls R and plots a surface while button 2 plots a contour. If I launch the application and click on button 1, I correctly see the surface plot but then I would like to click on button 2 to open a new window with the counter plot. Unfortunately, if I try to do so the app freezes and I cannot go on. So I have added button 3 with the intention to close the R engine if it is running. The idea was to kill the R instance and reopen it when clicking on button 2. But this doesn't work either. Is there a way to fix my problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDotNet;

namespace mySurface
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dllPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\i386\";
        REngine.SetDllDirectory(dllPath);
        REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstanceFromID("RDotNet");

        if (engine.IsRunning == false)
        {
            engine.Initialize();
        }

        var x = engine.Evaluate("x <- 1:100").AsNumeric();
        var y = engine.Evaluate("y <- 5:105").AsNumeric();
        engine.Evaluate("model = function (a, b){23.86+5.525*b-2.5725*a-6.6413*b^2-5.1862*a^2}"); //evaluate function
        engine.Evaluate("z = outer(x, y ,model)");
        engine.Evaluate("persp(x,y,z)");
        //Console.WriteLine(x[0]);
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dllPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\i386\";
        REngine.SetDllDirectory(dllPath);
        REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstanceFromID("RDotNet");

        if (engine.IsRunning == false)
        {
            engine.Initialize();
        }

        var x = engine.Evaluate("x <- 1:100").AsNumeric();
        var y = engine.Evaluate("y <- 5:105").AsNumeric();
        engine.Evaluate("model = function (a, b){23.86+5.525*b-2.5725*a-6.6413*b^2-5.1862*a^2}"); //evaluate function
        engine.Evaluate("z = outer(x, y ,model)");
        engine.Evaluate("contour(x,y,z, nlevels = 10)");

        //Console.WriteLine(x[0]);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstanceFromID("RDotNet");
        if (engine.IsRunning == false)
        {
            engine.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using R.NET 1.5.5 or less. The latest version is 1.5.16 and the initialisation procedure is significantly different. The [answer to a recent post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180843/2752565) provides more details. Issues with attempts at multiple initialisations of R tipycally used to lead to the symptoms you describe, and the new API tries to prevent this.